# How to add Edge as my debug browser in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 yesterday. I want to be able to use MS Edge when I debug my code in Visual Studio 2012.

I can't find the browser executable nor do I know if I need any special command line parameters necessary to make it work right.

Any hints or tips on this?

Comment: not sure, but it's not possible to integrate MS Edge into visual studio due to Edge is a Metro Browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add Microsoft Edge to your browser list to run directly into Microsoft Edge browser. As you can see click on browser switcher as in below image and click on "**Browse With...**".

[image: Browser Switcher]

Now click on Add button

[image: Add New Browser]

and type "C:\WINDOWS\system32\LaunchWinApp.exe" into Program input, leave Argument as blank and type appropriate friendly name and hit Okay.

[image: Microsoft Edge Browser Settings]

Comment: If I do this, and choose Edge as my browser, when I start a debugging session, the page still opens in Chrome. This `LaunchWinApp.exe` does nothing when you run it without arguments, and I assume it is a general too to open Windows apps. Just how does it open Edge when run without arguments?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even copying the DDE parameters from browsers.xml.
But this works: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe". Source:
https://superuser.com/questions/1338811/how-to-start-edge-by-calling-c-windows-systemapps-microsoft-microsoftedge-8weky

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the location for the Edge executable, nor with command lines execution, but here is a work-around to get you started;

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to start your application in your default browser, then copy+paste the respective URL from your default browser into Edge.

The requests that you submit from Edge to your URL are still processed by your development "server" - this is where your debugger will be attached, so your *server-side* breakpoints will still get triggered.

This will work for IIS and IIS Express.

Answer (score 2):

C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe

is the location of microsoft Edge.

You can get this location from Task manager->Microsoft Edge> Properties

Comment: That doesn't help you since you can't run it with params like a normal browser.

Comment: This exe doesn't exist on my machine, maybe it depends on Edge version.
But this works: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe". Source:
https://superuser.com/questions/1338811/how-to-start-edge-by-calling-c-windows-systemapps-microsoft-microsoftedge-8weky

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine but I had a problem getting Edge to browse my localhost where I do my web site development.  Turns out Edge is locked down by default to not allow browsing to localhost.

To fix this, fire up Fiddler (or install it then fire it up), the click on the WinConfig button in the main toolbar of Fiddler.  You'll see the AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility.  Find Microsoft Edge in the list, click the check box next to it, and click Save.

Like magic Edge should now load your site on localhost.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the browser in the *Browse With* dialog with:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe".

Source:
https://superuser.com/questions/1338811/how-to-start-edge-by-calling-c-windows-systemapps-microsoft-microsoftedge-8weky