# Launching Edge with a file URL

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-edge

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626509/how-to-launch-ms-edge-from-c-sharp-winforms) shows how to launch Edge with a web URL from C#:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");`

However, this doesn't seem to work with file URLs.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:file:///C:/foo/bar.html");`

launches Edge, but the file is not displayed. Instead, Edge opens to its default page. Pasting the same URL ("file:///C:/foo/bar.html") into the Edge address bar works fine, and if I right-click the file in Explorer and choose Open With->Edge, the same URL appears in the address bar.

Does anyone know how to launch Edge with a file URL?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798285/how-can-i-open-a-local-html-file-in-microsoft-edge-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798285/how-can-i-open-a-local-html-file-in-microsoft-edge-browser)

Comment: Currently you cannot open local files through `microsoft-edge` url scheme. There is a feature request in uservoice regarding to this feature: [Allow to open local files from Command Line](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/11422089-allow-to-open-local-files-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Edge does not support the file: protocol via the command line at this time.

However, it *is* currently possible to launch Edge with a local file using `IApplicationActivationManager`. The necessary code can be extracted from the C# version of MicrosoftEdgeLauncher and integrated into a C# application.

See 'MicrosoftEdgeLauncherCsharp' at https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/edge-launcher. To launch with a local file, use 'file:///*d:/path/filename.ext*' as the `arguments` parameter to `ActivateApplication`.

Answer (score 3):

One dirty solution: first set your default launcher as Edge.

Suppose the file you want to open is `file:///C:/foo/bar.html`, you can launch it using `explorer`:

```
explorer file:///C:/foo/bar.html
```

Which will open Edge with the HTML for you.
This seems to be the only solution after `start microsoft-edge:file:///C:/foo/bar.html` no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

With C# 10 on .Net6 and Win10, only the following worked for me:

```
 Process.Start("msedge", "d:/myfile.html");
```

There are a number of other answers on the site which don't appear to work any more.