# How to Combine: Open target link in specific browser and file://[unc path]

Tags: html, href

Is there a way to combine the ability to open a link in a specific browser.

`HREF="microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com/">Open Google in Edge`

and

`file://server/path`

In Edge the link opens up the UNC folder in a new file explorer window, but due to security concerns many other browsers block this function.

Is there a way to build a link that will to open up Edge to this location?

Comment: This isn't _exactly_ the same but these reference the current limitations of Edge protocol/command line 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798285/how-can-i-open-a-local-html-file-in-microsoft-edge-browser  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798285/how-can-i-open-a-local-html-file-in-microsoft-edge-browser

Ultimately: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. On the page I want a link to open of the folder I have a link to a "middle" page.

```
<A HREF="microsoft-edge:http://mysite/t.html">Open Folder t</A><br/>
```

And on this "middle" page t.html I have added a redirect to the folder.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=file://///path/toFolder/t" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>If the folder does not open in 5 seconds, <a href="file://///path/toFolder/t" target="_explorer.exe">click here</a>.</p>
</body>
```

It's not pretty but it works. I would love to improve this solution if anyone can see and suggest changes.